# In Tensorflow, how do you include a pre-trained model in a custom model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've got a custom model that I've pre-trained in a [separate notebook](https://vehiclereidjupyternotebook.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/vae_source_code.html) called `vae` which I've saved using `vae.save()`.

I'm now looking to implement a model which is a full training pipeline containing the pre-trained `vae` and some other (including a ResNet-50 from the Tensorflow gallery).

In the Tensorflow documentation about [Making new Layers and Models via subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) it doesn't mention anything about including models in subclassed models.

My question is **how do I include my pre-trained VAE in a new subclassed model?**

I've already tried writing the code below, which works fine for training, but I haven't seen implementations like it elsewhere and I'm getting errors when trying to do `reid.save()` or `reid.summary()` on the model, so I presume there is a better way to do it:

```
class ReId(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vae, num_ids, **kwargs):
        super(ReId, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.vae = vae
        self.convex_combination = ConvexCombination()
        self.resnet_50 = resnet50
        self.glob_avg_pool = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.bnneck = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.num_ids = num_ids
        self.final_fc_layer = keras.layers.Dense(self.num_ids)
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.vae_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="vae_loss"
        )
        self.classification_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="classification_loss")
        self.triplet_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="triplet_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.vae_loss_tracker,
            # Classification loss is cross-entropy loss here
            self.classification_loss_tracker,
            self.triplet_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        y = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Calculate VAE loss
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.vae.encoder(x)
            reconstruction = self.vae.decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                    keras.losses.mean_squared_error(x, reconstruction)
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            
            # Calculate VAE loss
            vae_loss = reconstruction_loss + (LAMBDA * kl_loss)
            
            embedding_output = self.call(x)
            bnneck_output = self.bnneck(embedding_output)
            training_output = self.final_fc_layer(bnneck_output)

            # Calculate triplet loss
            triplet_loss = tfa.losses.triplet_semihard_loss(y_true=y, y_pred=embedding_output)

            # Calculate cross-entropy loss
            ce_loss = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, training_output)
            
            # Sum up the losses
            total_loss = triplet_loss + ce_loss + (TOTAL_LOSS_VAE_MULTIPLIER * vae_loss)
            
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.classification_loss_tracker.update_state(ce_loss)
        self.triplet_loss_tracker.update_state(triplet_loss)
        self.vae_loss_tracker.update_state(vae_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "classification loss:": self.classification_loss_tracker.result(),
            "triplet loss:": self.triplet_loss_tracker.result(),
            "vae loss:": self.vae_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(ReId, self).get_config()
        config.update({"num_ids": self.num_ids})
        return config

    def call(self, data):
        recon_img = self.vae(data)
        convex_combo_input = [data, (data - recon_img)]
        convex_combo_output = self.convex_combination(convex_combo_input)
        final_output = self.glob_avg_pool(self.resnet_50(convex_combo_output))
        return final_output
```

Comment: What happen when you save that model specifically?

Comment: ```ValueError: Model <__main__.ReId object at 0x7fe554658590> cannot be saved because the input shapes have not been set. Usually, input shapes are automatically determined from calling `.fit()` or `.predict()`. To manually set the shapes, call `model.build(input_shape)`.```

Comment: @Đinh Anh Vũ The above post shows the error given when saving and asking for a summary of the model.

Comment: You can try what's given in the error log. Use `model.build( input_shape )` and then try saving your model.

Comment: @Shubham Panchal Unfortunately this doesn't work, even after ```.fit()``` or ```.build()``` are used, I still get the same error.

Comment: @magmacollaris try to add [Input layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) in `.call()`